# how to create a new key from a value of another key Python

Tags: python, list, dictionary, key-value

I have a list of dictionaries that looks like the following:

```
data = [{'Name': 'Paul', 'Date': '20200412', 'ID': '1020'}, {'Name': 'Frank', 'Date': '20200413', 'ID': '1030'}, {'Name': 'Anna', 'Date': '20200414', 'ID': '1040'}]
```

I need to create a new list of dictionaries, where ID's value would be the key, and the value is another dictionary with key/values associated with this specific ID. 
This is the desired output:

```
new_data = [{'1020': {'Name': 'Paul', 'Date': '20200412'}},
{'1030': {'Name': 'Frank', 'Date': '20200413'}},
{'1040': {'Name': 'Anna', 'Date': '20200414'}}]
```

I have tried:

```
for index, my_dict in enumerate(data):
    new_data = []
    key = my_dict['ID']
    new_data.append(key)
```

But that only assigned the key value, not sure how to push it into into a new dict along with other key/values.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> [{i['ID']: {k:v for k,v in i.items() if k != 'ID'}} for i in data]
[{'1020': {'Name': 'Paul', 'Date': '20200412'}},
 {'1030': {'Name': 'Frank', 'Date': '20200413'}},
 {'1040': {'Name': 'Anna', 'Date': '20200414'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this list comprehension:

```
[{x["ID"]: {k: v for k, v in x.items() if k != "ID"}} for x in data]
```

Which assigns `ID` as the parent key to the dictionary, and filters out the `ID` key from the child dictionary inside a dict comprehension

Which could be broken down into this:

```
result = []
for x in data:
    result.append({x["ID"]: {k: v for k, v in x.items() if k != "ID"}})
```

And even to a straightforward loop approach:

```
result = []
for x in data:
    dic = {x["ID"]: {}}
    for k, v in x.items():
        if k != "ID":
            dic[x["ID"]][k] = v
    result.append(dic)
```

**Output:**

```
[{'1020': {'Name': 'Paul', 'Date': '20200412'}}, {'1030': {'Name': 'Frank', 'Date': '20200413'}}, {'1040': {'Name': 'Anna', 'Date': '20200414'}}]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
new_data = []
for index, my_dict in enumerate(data):
    key = my_dict['ID']
    del my_dict['ID']
    new_data.append({key:data[index]})
```

Comment: Can you provide some explanation for why this solution works?

Comment: This solution works because I am deleting the key 'ID' from the dict `my_dict` and this variable points to the same memory location of `data[index]`. Hence deleting the key from the iteration variable is good enough in this scenario. It could also have been simply `new_data.append({key:my_dict})`
`>>> id(data[index])
4358425408
>>> id(my_dict)
4358425408
>>> `

Comment: This is the output -->  
```>>> new_data=  
[{'1020': {'Date': '20200412', 'Name': 'Paul'}},  
{'1030': {'Date': '20200413', 'Name': 'Frank'}},  
{'1040': {'Date': '20200414', 'Name': 'Anna'}}]```

Answer (score 0):

To add the other values you simply need to create a new dict like this:

```
new_data.append( key:{
'name':my_dict['name']
'Date':my_dict['date']
}
```

You also don't need to make the 'key' variable, you can just use 'my_dict['ID']'